# How do I use JSON properly to pass Events/EventSources to FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, json, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

My end goal to pass eventSources via JSON dynamically. Before I even get to producing the JSON content dynamically, I am trying to use the documentation example to pass a simple single event via a JSON URL into my event tag, written manually.

I can see the URL works because I can echo the results in my wordpress website via php, but the JS script i'm passing the JSON URL to just crashes the calendar. I'm really scratching my head on this one.

There's also mention of  the prev/next buttons triggering a GET to the JSON with the local timezone dates (say for the range of the currently displayed month). How am I supposed to syntax the json so as to have the event call find the data points range? I'm just really confused about all this.

JSON File: calendar.json

```
{
    "title" : "something",
    "start" : "2019-04-23"  
}
```

PHP File: page-calendar.php

```
<?php
    //Wordpress function for URL to the file location
    $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/calendar.json'; 
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $content = json_decode($data);

    echo $content->title; // Just to test if the URL works 
    echo $content->start; // This echos just fine

    ?>
<html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script>
          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
              plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],

              events: $url;
            });

            calendar.render();
          });
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id='calendar'></div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either :/. I think being inside the event from the DOM restricts heavily the kind of things I can pass, In the FullCalendar documentation it seems to explicitly define a URL to a PHP file (wondering if sending it to a JSON file is the problem here.) Could a PHP file called with a GET (which the event tag does I believe) return a JSON response? No idea how this works honestly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON needs to be an array of events (even if the array only contains one object). Currently you have a single object, and fullCalendar won't read that.

Make your `calendar.json` file look like this:

```
[
  {
    "title" : "something",
    "start" : "2019-04-23"  
  }
]
```

You'll also need to change the code a bit so that your PHP `$url` variable is treated as PHP and rendered, and also so the output is treated as a string by JS, not just injected into the JS as-is:

```
events: "<?php echo $url; ?>"
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much. You seem like the person active around the FullCalendar tag lol expect to see more dumb questions from me pop up. Truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your php and fullcalendar is on the same page you may need this

```
<?php
   $url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/calendar.json';
?>

<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],

          events: "<?php echo $url; ?>";
        });

        calendar.render();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Remember to check your output of calendar.json.
It should look like so

```
            [
             {
              "title" : "something",
              "start" : "2019-04-23"  
             }
            ];
```

Comment: 1) What is the point of making PHP read the file and then pass it onto the page, when the URL of the JSON file could be given to fullCalendar directly? 2) Even if it were necessary for PHP to read the JSON file, what is the point of decoding it and then immediately encoding it again straight afterwards? You just end up with the same result you started with. This answer involves pointless make-work and unnecessary code.

Comment: @ADyson you are right. I totally missed that he is calling .json file already. I thought he is calling another api which is then decoded to json. I am going to update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure, if this might solve your problem, also I don't know about WordPress. However, maybe you might try using WordPress built-in functions, maybe in this case, you might try [wp_remote_get](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) or find similar functions to use instead of `file_get_content()`. Because, maybe for security or permission reasons, you are not allowed to get contents from some URLs, not sure.

You might test it with `chmod($url, 0000);` to see if you are allowed to change the permission of the file. Then, if it was a permission issue, you could just add `chmod()`to your script:

```
//Wordpress function for URL to the file location
$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/calendar.json';
chmod($url, 0777);
//$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = wp_remote_get($url);
$content = json_decode($data);
chmod($url, 0755);

echo $content->title;
echo $content->start;
```

Your PHP codes seem to be fine. Maybe, `var_dump($url);` to make sure everything is fine.

Also, you might try changing

```
events: $url;
```

to

```
events: <?php echo $url; ?>
```

Comment: file_get_content works. I'm using it to echo my URL information as a test. But i'm not using that variable inside the script. I'm using the $URL just before which is the path to the JSON file location. Unfortunately, the var_dump isn't working either